# Reference other UserControls within a ListBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox, user-controls

The problem I can't seem to fix is something I'm embarrassingly becoming annoyed about. I have a ListBox of UserControls, and from a Button event, I want to manipulate the other UserControls within the ListBox.

For test purposes I have a simple UserControl (UserControl1) with one button (ButtonNotify).

I am adding the UserControls to a ListBox (MyListBox).

```
        For i = 0 To 2
            Dim TestItem As New UserControl1
            TestItem.ButtonNotify.Content = "Blank"
            MyListBox.Items.Add(TestItem)
        Next
```

So I start with the button text displaying "Blank". When I click the button I have it saying "Yes":

```
ButtonNotify.Content = "Yes"
```

Works fine of course. However, when I do this I want the other two UserControls to display "No".

So If I click item 0, I want it to display "Yes" (this works) but I want the other two items, item 1 and 2, to display "No".
If I click item 1, display "Yes", item 0 and 2 display "No", and so on.

My problem is I can't seem to find a way to access the other UserControls in the ListBox.

I'm trying things like:

For each UserControl1 in MyListBox, and variants, without success.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: This is not the way you would typically use a ListBox. You would instead implement the MVVM pattern, where you would declare a DataTemplate with a Button that has its Content and Command properties bound to properties of a view model item class. The ItemSource of the ListBox is then bound to a collection of those items. The communication between items would take place in the view model, not in the view.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the comment but that (MVVM, DataTemplates, Binding) is far too over my head. I'm just trying to access one usercontrol (same type) from another, in a listbox.

Comment: If you have learned it once it will make your life a lot easier forever.

Comment: @Clemens I'm sure you're right, 100%, but I don't have 'forever' lol. I'm an old guy just doing a personal project in my own time for myself. Anyway, thanks for the comment. Maybe someone else can chip in.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, here is a working example using C#. Sorry, I am not a VB developer.

The idea here is to add an event to your UserControl1 called `SelectedEvent`. When the `ButtonNotify` is clicked, we set its `Content` to `"Yes"` and raise the `SelectedEvent`.

The `MainWindow` subscribes to this event and will then set the proper state of the other buttons.

### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SO.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace SO
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var testItem = new UserControl1
                {
                    ButtonNotify =
                    {
                        Content = "Blank"
                    }
                };

                testItem.SelectedEvent += OnUserControl1Selected;
                
                MyListBox.Items.Add(testItem);
            }
        }

        private void OnUserControl1Selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sourceItem = sender as UserControl1;
            
            foreach (var item in MyListBox.Items)
            {
                if (item is UserControl1 testItem && testItem != sourceItem)
                {
                    testItem.ButtonNotify.Content = "No";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SO.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonNotify"
            Click="ButtonNotify_OnClick" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonNotify_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonNotify.Content = "Yes";
            SelectedEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public delegate void SelectedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
        
        public event EventHandler SelectedEvent;
    }
}
```